# embed json file within d3.js (d3.layout.partition)

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am using this:
http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/partition.html

instead of d3.json("flare.json", function(root) {

how do i make it use the json file within the html, like say i have

```
var json = [{
"name": "flare",
"children": [
{"name": "analytics",
"children": [
{"name": "cluster","children": [{"name": "AgglomerativeCluster", "size": 3938},
{"name": "CommunityStructure", "size": 3812},
{"name": "HierarchicalCluster", "size": 6714},
{"name": "MergeEdge", "size": 743}
]
},
```

and i want to use this instead of an external json file, how do i achieve this?

Link to json file: http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/flare.json

Any JSFiddle example please?

Thank you.

Comment: This is not very complicated fix, if you can share ur code in fiddle or plunker. I can edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You will achieve this by two method**:

1.you can  assign the JSON data to variable name then You can build any layout

2.use one function to get the `JSON` data

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/w7Ypb/2/) for 1 solution

```
var root = json;
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/w7Ypb/1/)** for 2 solution

```
var root = getData();
  var g = vis.selectAll("g")
      .data(partition.nodes(root))
    .enter().append("svg:g")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.y) + "," + y(d.x) + ")"; })
      .on("click", click);
```

Comment: Fiddle example with this http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/partition.html please?

Comment: How to get this working with version 4?, the layout partition does no longer exist and its replacement does not contain a value property